# MySql query tuning for min/max dates by group

Tags: mysql, max, grouping, min

I have a table with several million rows of data. I have a primary key on id, and a compound unique key on col2, col3, col4 and my_date.
Sample data is shown here...

```
id   col2 col3 col4 my_date
1    1    1    1    2020-01-03 02:00:00
2    1    2    1    2020-01-03 01:00:00
3    1    3    1    2020-01-03 03:00:00
4    2    1    1    2020-02-03 01:00:00
5    2    2    1    2020-02-03 02:00:00
6    2    3    1    2020-02-03 03:00:00
7    3    1    1    2020-03-03 03:00:00
8    3    2    1    2020-03-03 02:00:00
9    3    3    1    2020-03-03 01:00:00
```

I want to get the min and max dates, grouped by col2.

The rules are...

1. For each col4 there will be multiple col2's
2. For each col2 there will be multiple col3's
3. The dates associated with col2 can be in any order
4. The min/max dates for each group will all be within 7 days of each other.

My idea was to get the min date from the first id and add 1 week to it. Then use this data as a range restricter to get the minimum date for each col2 group, and the opposite for the max dates.

I have created the following query...

```
SELECT t1.col2, t1.min_date, t2.max_date
FROM (
    SELECT min(table.my_date) AS min_date, table.col2 AS col2
    FROM table
    JOIN (
        SELECT table.id AS id, date_add(table.my_date, interval 7 day) AS min_date
        FROM table
        JOIN (
            SELECT min(table.id) AS min_id
            FROM table
            WHERE table.col4 = 1
        ) AS t3
        ON table.id = t3.min_id
    ) AS t3
    ON table.my_date < t3.min_date
    GROUP BY table.col2
) AS t1
JOIN (
    SELECT max(table.my_date) AS max_date, table.col2 AS col2
    FROM table
    JOIN (
        SELECT table.id AS id, date_sub(table.my_date, interval 7 day) AS max_date
        FROM table
        JOIN (
            SELECT max(table.id) AS max_id
            FROM table
            WHERE table.col4 = 1
        ) AS t5
        ON table.id = t5.max_id
    ) AS t4
    ON table.my_date > t4.max_date
    GROUP BY table.col2
) AS t2
ON t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

The query runs OK and returns the correct results. It is currently taking about 12 seconds to run.

Is there a better way to write this query to improve the performance/readability?

Comment: If you found a better solution do not forget to define index on all columns also.

Comment: I already have the index on all 4 columns, or is that not what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to get the min and max dates, grouped by col2." -- Then simply have

```
INDEX(col2, my_date)
```

You currently have `UNIQUE(col2, col3, col4, my_date)`, correct? If you are willing to shuffle that, you won't need my extra index:  `UNIQUE(col2, my_date, col3, col4)`.

Then, this is quite efficient:

```
SELECT col2, MIN(my_date), MAX(my_date)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY col2;
```

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` will show that the index is "covering" by saying "Using index".

Comment: Hi Rick, the reason I have the date as the last item in the index is that I also use that index for selecting ranges of dates, which is why I have it at the end. I believe if it is not at the end, then anything to the right of the date will not be used as part of the index, unless I am mistaken? I could create a new index, but I would only need it for this particular situation, so seems overkill.

Comment: @Wannabe-Coder - Yes, but...  My SELECT needs col2 first and date second.  Columns after that don't matter.  Your current UNIQUE will still work, but less efficiently since it will only use `col2`.  `col3` and `col4` are in the way of making use of `date.  More:  [_Index Cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: There are situations where you need different "composite" indexes for different queries.  Without knowing the _other_ queries, I can't say how many different indexes is optimal.

Comment: Hi Rick, I think I am overthinking it when I should just create a new index, but my concern was not to impact the insert speed too much. Thanks also, for the link.

Comment: @Wannabe-Coder - INSERT speed is rarely an issue.  Non-unique indexes are updated in a delayed, semi-optimized way (cf "change buffering").  Do you have millions of inserts per day?

Comment: I will be performing multiple batched inserts per week, with each batch containing over 1M records.

Comment: A million per _day_ is unlikely to be a problem; a million per _hour_ is more challenging.